# Flash Drive Issue

Tags: iso

So I used Startup Disk Creator on Ubuntu 13.04. What I was trying to burn didn't work, so it stopped. I see files on my flash drive from the installment, but I can't delete them or add any new files to my flash drive. Any fix? Format via the Startup Disk Creator just fails after attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Try gparted to format it... One step at a time... i always had this trouble with startup disk creator. So I started using either unetbootin and no problems dd command from terminal... this works perfectly...

`sudo dd if=ubuntu.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=4M`

replace ubuntu.iso with the correct iso file name and replace sdc with the correct device.

Comment: Device name? It's just "Pendrive". And thanks for the response! I hope I'd be able to do this.

Comment: Can I not do the terminal part and try the Gparted one? How do I tell which drive is which on GParted?

Comment: GParted won't let me delete it.